# Which SOLID principle is violated in the following code?

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles

Which SOLID principle is violated in the following code?

```java
public class A {
  void hello(){
    //some code here
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  int i;
  void hello(){
    i++;
  }
}
```

I think that LSP (Liskov Substitution Principle) is violated because the subclass `B` cannot be substituted into a variable of type `A`. I am really not sure about this, and somehow I think that none of the SOLID principles are violated here.

Another thing I have been thinking about is that `i` is declared without any access modifier. Should this be a violation? If yes, which violation?

Comment: This question is off topic and you should not ask questions of this nature on Stack Overflow. Check out [How to write a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should try asking here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the problem with not declaring `i` private?

From Effective Java 3rd edition:

> **If a class is accessible outside its package, provide accessor methods** to preserve the flexibility to change the class’s internal representation. If a public class exposes its data fields, all hope of changing its representation is lost because client code can be distributed far and wide.
>
> However, **if a class is package-private or is a private nested class, there is nothing inherently wrong with exposing its data fields.**

I think it makes pretty clear when need to expose `i` and when not to.

On the other hand, LSP is not violated because you can always write

```java
A a = new B();
```

It's generally not appropriate to evaluate which of the SOLID principles are violated with classes whose meaning is not clear (like classes `A` and `B` in your case)

But if you know (contextual) meaning of each class then we can make some comments. (For example an `Employee` `is-a` `Person` and also a `Student` `is-a` `Person` - so LSP should work here - you should be able to assign an `Employee` object to a `Person` reference and similar thing goes for `Student` object also)

Comment: @Nff why don't you accept the answer, if it *makes sense*?

Comment: @deHaar sorry, I was waiting for other answers. I accepted it just now.